# Switch statement doesn't works as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

I'm trying to understand whats wrong with my code here:

```
 switch(arr){
case [0, 0]:
  console.log("hereee")
  return 0;
case [0, 1]:
  return 1;
case [0, 2]:
  return 2;
case [1, 0]:
  return 3;
case [1, 1]:
  return 4;
case [1, 2]:
  return 5;
case [2, 0]:
  return 6;
case [2, 1]:
  return 7;
case [2, 2]:
  return 8;
default:
  console.log("but heree")
  return -1;
        }
```

As you see it checks array and should return number defending on provided array values, for example when I pass [1, 2] I expect output to be 5, if I pass [0, 0] it should be 0, right? but I'm always getting default value -1; Please help me to understand reason behind this.

Comment: Here is a good method.  According to this answer, Arrays will always return false.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818127/using-an-array-through-a-switch-statement-in-javascript

Comment: because  that is not how you compare arrays... if ([0,0]===[0,0]) would never work. You are going to have to rethink it.

Comment: In JS arrays are compared by reference not by values hence `[] !== []` and `[1, 2] !== [1, 2]`

Comment: @Carcigenicate and that would not work either....

Comment: thanks guys I suspected it was the case, I guess I will have to switch to if statement and compare with == or is there any other better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `switch` only for primitives. JS uses `===`  for comparison in switch statements, and `[0,0]===[0,0]`  is `false`.